# Matching exactly 8 digits with 0 or more dashes

Tags: regex, string, numbers, phone-number

I am trying to match an exactly 8 digit phone number that has 0 or more dashes in it. For example, the following should all match:

```
12345678
123456-78
1234-5678
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
```

If I ignore the dashes, it is rather simple. I can just use:

```
[\d]{8}
```

If I want to match a string containing at least 8 characters (digits and dashes) I can use:

```
[\d-]{8,}
```

However, here I can't put an upper bound on the number of characters because I don't know how many dashes the number would have.

The only way I thought of would be to use:

```
[0-9][-]?[0-9][-]?[0-9][-]?[0-9][-]?[0-9][-]?[0-9][-]?[0-9][-]?[0-9]
```

However, this seems really messy for something that (at least in my mind) seems simple. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to strip everything EXCEPT digits from the string before you apply the regex? then you don't have to worry about any dashes, because they won't be there at all.

Comment: @MarcB I can't strip things. This is for the `pattern` attribute of the `<input type="tel">` element.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you don't need to use the brackets (`[…]`) if there is only 1 element inside them

Comment: Use`^[0-9](-?[0-9]){7}$`. Anubhava's `^([0-9]-?){8}$` is short but allows a trailing hyphen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional `-` after each digit:

```
^([0-9]-?){8}$
```

If your regex supports `\d` then use:

```
^(\d-?){8}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV0aS5/1)

Comment: Shorter - `^(\d-?){8}$`

Comment: Longer - `^([0123456789]-?){8}$`

Comment: I've added a note for `\d` but it isn't supported in all the tools like `sed` or `awk`

Comment: @Sean Huh, just that long? `^([0123456789]-?)([0123456789]-?)([0123456789]-?)([0123456789]-?)([0123456789]-?)([0123456789]-?)([0123456789]-?)$`

Comment: @nicael, even better. It's always best to be explicit. `/s` (but that will only match 7 digits)

Comment: The small problem with this is that it will allow ending on hyphen. I would recommend `^([0-9]-?){7}[0-9]$`

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```js
^[0-9](-?[0-9]){7}$
^([0-9]-?){8}\b$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/sZ2aU3/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/sZ2aU3/13), where `\b` is used to make sure the last char is a digit (that is a word char).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]` to match a digit since `\d` in various regex flavors may match more than just ASCII digits from `0` to `9`.
- `(-?[0-9]){7}` - matches 7 sequences of an optional hyphen and a digit, and  **will not allow trailing hyphen at the end of the string**.
- `([0-9]-?){8}` - matches eight occurrences of a digit followed with an optional `-` char
- `\b$` - is a trick to make sure the last char is of a word type. Since the pattern can only match a `-` (a non-word char) or a digit at the end, `\b` automatically makes sure the last char is a digit.

Comment: Good idea not allowing the trailing hyphen like that. In this case it really doesn't matter since all the hyphens will be stripped programatically after the regex anyway, so I'm just going to keep it slightly simpler with anubhava's answer.

Comment: I see, if you do not use JS, you will be still better off using `\A(-?[0-9]){8}\z` since in almost any regex `$` matches before a final newline in a string meaning the "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8\n" will [get matched with `^(-?[0-9]){8}$`](https://regex101.com/r/eK6vE6/1) (note there is a linebreak in the demo text).

Comment: I am using JS, but this is *before* the JS, from the `patern` attribute of the HTML5 `<input type="tel">` element. It really doesn't matter too much if there are trailing characters because every non-numeric character is later stripped by the JS. However even if it did matter, this element [doesn't permit CR or LF in the value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html#input.tel.attrs.value) (at least in supported browsers).

Comment: @Mike I have updated my answer that still does not allow a trailing `-` and is "simple"